# Using Jquery to call an ASMX service in sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, asmx

The service I'm trying to call is deployed as part of a visual web part. If i call it directly: 
_layouts/service.asmx
I get the expected service page, showing me the functions I want to call. 
When I do the Jquery Ajax call (it works just fine on my development server) I get a 500 error back from the server.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myserver/_layouts/service.asmx/GetLinksToAllFav',
    data: "{'tag': '" + $('#MyTag').val() + "', 'TagMaxLength': '" + $('#TagMaxLength').val() + "'}",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#MyFav').html(data.d);
        $('#MyFav').show(100);
    },
    error: function (all, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown); }
});
```

Response    HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: my friend if you get 500 Server Error, there is NO way to help you if you show us the CLIENT code... you need to debug your service.asmx...

Comment: what do you mean with "call it directly, it works"? How you call a POST request with data directly?

Comment: Call it directly: I input the url http://localhost/_lauouts/service.asmx in the browser, getting the service page, there I can choose the function I want (GetLinksToAllFav) I then get a form I can input data in and call the function, getting the expected result. It's the AJAX call that gets me a 500 error.

Comment: Moss logs just shows: "Entering monitored scope ", then "name= Request.." then "Leaving monitored scope .."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work I had to add the following to the web.config file.

```
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
```